# Traversing a tree, predecessor and successor

Tags: data-structures, tree-traversal

I am facing a couple of doubts in tree data structure.

1) Is tree traversing (Preorder, Inorder, Postorder) possible in all types of trees or only binary trees.

2) If the first point is valid, then can we simply Inorder traverse a tree and store the elements in an array.

And then by using that array can we find predecessor and successor, as elements coming before and after a given element.

Comment: What research did you do? From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal): "The following algorithms are described for a binary tree, but they may be generalized to other trees as well."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

Tree traversing (Preorder, Inorder, Postorder) possible in all types of trees 
   not only in binary trees.

every tree contains child nodes.( binary tree 2, ternary tree 3 etc).

We need to define our own way of traversing the trees.
lets take example of ternary tree.

Preorder : visit(root.data) - >root.left -> root.middle ->  root.right

postorder: root.left -> root.middle  - > root.right -> visit(root.data)

inorder   :  root.left -> root.middle -> visit(root.data) - > root.right

**Preorder** : visit all **k** child  nodes( from left to right) after **first** visiting root node.

**Postorder** : visit all **k** child nodes (from left to right) **before** visiting root node.

**Inorder** : visit **k/2** child nodes( from left to right) and visit root node then visit remaining **k/2** child nodes.

2. we can store the tree in an array by inorder traversing. 
   we can find the predecessor and successor from that array by how we did inorder traversal.

for a binary tree, predecessor = left child, successor = right child

for ternary tree, predecessor = left child or middle child , successor = middle child or right child. ( we have to specify it based on our requirement)